# LINQ for comparing two lists with complex entities

Tags: c#, linq

We have a class structure as listed below

```
public class ItemDTO
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}


public class CostPageDTO
{
    public string CostPageNumber { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; }
}
```

There are two lists – 1) List of Costpage and Items present in the database 2) User selected costpages

**QUESTION**

We need to compare these two lists and get a resultant list that has costpages for which the count of distinct items in the actual set and selected set are same.

What is the `best performing` LINQ for this  (in Chain-Method approach)?

**EXPECTED RESULT**

Expected Result based on the following scenario is a list with only 1 costpage – “C2” (for which items match)

[image]

**CODE**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<CostPageDTO> selectedCostPageAndItems = GetSelectedCostPageAndItems();
    List<CostPageDTO> actualItems = GetActualItems();

    //LINQ code to get the matching count costPages

}


private static List<CostPageDTO> GetSelectedCostPageAndItems()
{
    ItemDTO i1 = new ItemDTO();
    i1.ItemID = 1;

    ItemDTO i2 = new ItemDTO();
    i2.ItemID = 2;

    ItemDTO i3 = new ItemDTO();
    i3.ItemID = 3;


    CostPageDTO c1 = new CostPageDTO();
    c1.CostPageNumber = "C1";
    c1.Items = new List<ItemDTO>();
    c1.Items.Add(i1);

    CostPageDTO c2 = new CostPageDTO();
    c2.CostPageNumber = "C2";
    c2.Items = new List<ItemDTO>();
    c2.Items.Add(i2);
    c2.Items.Add(i3);

    //CostPageDTO c2Duplicate = new CostPageDTO();
    //c2Duplicate.CostPageNumber = "C2";
    //c2Duplicate.Items = new List<ItemDTO>();
    //c2Duplicate.Items.Add(i2);
    //c2Duplicate.Items.Add(i3);

    List<CostPageDTO> selectedCostPageAndItems = new List<CostPageDTO>();
    selectedCostPageAndItems.Add(c1);
    selectedCostPageAndItems.Add(c2);
    //selectedCostPageAndItems.Add(c2Duplicate);

    return selectedCostPageAndItems;

}
private static List<CostPageDTO> GetActualItems()
{
    ItemDTO i1 = new ItemDTO();
    i1.ItemID = 1;

    ItemDTO i2 = new ItemDTO();
    i2.ItemID = 2;

    ItemDTO i3 = new ItemDTO();
    i3.ItemID = 3;

    ItemDTO i3Duplicate = new ItemDTO();
    i3Duplicate.ItemID = 3;

    CostPageDTO c1 = new CostPageDTO();
    c1.CostPageNumber = "C1";
    c1.Items = new List<ItemDTO>();
    c1.Items.Add(i1);
    c1.Items.Add(i2);
    c1.Items.Add(i3);

    CostPageDTO c2 = new CostPageDTO();
    c2.CostPageNumber = "C2";
    c2.Items = new List<ItemDTO>();
    c2.Items.Add(i2);
    c2.Items.Add(i3);
    c2.Items.Add(i3Duplicate);

    List<CostPageDTO> actualItems = new List<CostPageDTO>();
    actualItems.Add(c1);
    actualItems.Add(c2);

    return actualItems;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will select your expected result:

**Method syntax:**

```
var result = selectedCostPageAndItems.SelectMany(scp => actualItems.Where(acp=>acp.CostPageNumber == scp.CostPageNumber),
                            (scp,acp)=> new {CostPageNumber = scp.CostPageNumber,
                                        scpItems = new HashSet<int>(scp.Items.Select(x=>x.ItemID)),
                                        acpItems = new HashSet<int>(acp.Items.Select(x=>x.ItemID))})
                        .Where(x => x.scpItems.SetEquals(x.acpItems))
                        .Select(x => x.CostPageNumber);
```

**Query comprehension syntax:**

```
var result = from cp1 in selectedCostPageAndItems
             from cp2 in actualItems
             let items1 = new HashSet<int>(cp1.Items.Select(x=>x.ItemID))
             let items2 = new HashSet<int>(cp2.Items.Select(x=>x.ItemID))
             where cp1.CostPageNumber == cp2.CostPageNumber
             && items1.SetEquals(items2)
             select cp1.CostPageNumber;
```

**Explanation:**

Find all pairs of selected (`scp`) and actual (`acp`) `CostPageDTO` with identical `CostPageNumber`

```
selectedCostPageAndItems.SelectMany(scp => actualItems.Where(acp=>acp.CostPageNumber == scp.CostPageNumber)
```

For each such pair (`scp` and `acp`), select the `CostPageNumber` and a set of `ItemDTO.ItemID` for the selected (`scpItems`) and actual (`acpItems`) `CostPageDTO`

```
(scp,acp)=> new {CostPageNumber = scp.CostPageNumber,
                                    scpItems = new HashSet<int>(scp.Items.Select(x=>x.ItemID)),
                                    acpItems = new HashSet<int>(acp.Items.Select(x=>x.ItemID))})
```

Finally select the `CostPageNumber` of the ones that have equal sets

```
Where(x => x.scpItems.SetEquals(x.acpItems)).Select(x => x.CostPageNumber)
```

The creation and the comparison of the [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is all **O(n)**